# Is there any way in flutter that I can fetch the physical screen size of the laptop and display the output screen as e.g. 700X900 for desktop app

Tags: flutter, desktop-application, flutter-packages

I am not able to change the default output screen in flutter to a certain specific resolution. I am also unable to remove the minimize and maximize buttons in the default app bar.

[in the image the resolution size is different I want it to be changed to 500 x 500 for all the screen sizes such as 14inchs, 17 inches laptop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcNiW.png). If I am setting 1500x1200 in a 14-inch lap it is increased in a 17-inch lap for the same resolution instead I want 900x700 to be fixed for different screen sizes - how can I attain that?

Or is there any way I can fetch the physical screen size and set the percentage to 80% or 60% of the output screen? For desktop applications in Windows, Linux, and macOS, not Android, or iOS!

Referred with https://github.com/polilluminato/simple-flutter-resizewindow where a button is being set and calling different resolutions such as desktop to a certain resolution 1440x900 and tab and mobile so on but I want the default app bar size to be changed so that I could not achieve also disabling the minimize and maximizing button of the default app bar.

I am unable to do all these is for the web application, not Android, or iOS, by window_manager I am able to achieve this but for different lap inches the resolution change how to fix this also want to remove the minimize and maximize button

```
await windowManager.setSize(Size(800, 600));
```

Or `desktop_window`:

```
Size size = await DesktopWindow.getWindowSize();
DesktopWindow.setWindowSize(Size(800,600));
DesktopWindow.setFullScreen(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

To get `Height` and `Width` of the Screen try :

```
double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
```

Comment: home: MediaQuery(
data: MediaQueryData(size: Size(800, 600)),
child: Scaffold(
          
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: Builder(
              builder: (context) {
                double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
                double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
                return Text(
                  'Screen size: $width x $height',
                 
                
      
for this above code just 800x600 is being displayed as output there is no change in the o/p screen size of flutter how can i achieve that ?

Comment: if (Platform.isWindows || Platform.isLinux || Platform.isMacOS) {
    await DesktopWindow.setWindowSize(const Size(1500, 1200));
    await DesktopWindow.setMinWindowSize(const Size(1500, 1200));
    await DesktopWindow.setMaxWindowSize(const Size(1500, 1200)); using this im able set but the main issue is it does the reflect the same in 17inch laptop and 14 inch laptop ? how do i solve this as there are different screen resolution how to set a constant size that is being reflected in all system ?

Comment: 1600 x 900 
1920 x 1080
2304×1440 
2560 x 1440 
2560×1600 
2880×1800 
3000 x 2000 
3200 x 1800 
3840 x 2160 these are the diff screen resolutions for these i want a fixed screen size of 900x700 or by fetching the physical screen size it should fit a standard size of 80% of the screen size how can that be done?

Comment: Don't pass static `Size` in `DesktopWindow.setWindowSize`.Try to pass this dynamically like `DesktopWindow.setWindowSize(Size(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.80, MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.80));`

Comment: Hello, @Sweta Kaarnapattu, It works or not?

Comment: I am,able to set the window size but consider for a 14inch lap the size is 1500x1200 , and running the same application in a 17 inch laptop size varies also with the ui i see changes as it reflects saying overflowed with so and so pixels this is the main issue im facing..! i want standard size that to be replicated in all window size no matter wt..!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the above question i asked with the below code : my concern was it should reflect the same size on an 17inch lap and 14inch lap and it was fixed ..!!

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
```

doWhenWindowReady(() {
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()
.renderView
.automaticSystemUiAdjustment = false;
final win = appWindow;
const initialSize = Size(800, 600);

```
win.minSize = initialSize;
win.maxSize = initialSize;
win.size = initialSize;
win.alignment = Alignment.center;

final screenSize = ui.window.physicalSize / ui.window.devicePixelRatio;
final dx = (screenSize.width - initialSize.width) / 2;
final dy = (screenSize.height - initialSize.height) / 2;
win.position = Offset(dx, dy);

win.show();
```